# C# Deserialization xml file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I try to deserialize xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XmlFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OBJECTS ITEM="ItemValue" TABLE_NAME="TableExample">
    </OBJECTS>
</XmlFile>
```

My deserialize class code looks like that:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("XmlFile")]
public class SerializeObject
{

    [XmlAttribute("ITEM")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("TABLE_NAME")]
    public string Table_Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try deserialize xml file i always got no errors and Item and Table_Name equals null. Why?

Thx for replay

Comment: More code would be usefull. My guess looking at the provided info is: You are not specifying the "OBJECTS" element. You're class defines "XmlFile/@ITEM" and "XmlFile/@TABLE_NAME" whereas the XML has an "OBJECTS" element in between.

Comment: I see the use of "Serializable" attribute (used for the RunTime serializers) AND the use of "XmlRoot/XmlAttribute" attributes which are intended for the XmlSerializer. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 7):

```
[XmlRoot("XmlFile")]
public class SerializableContainer
{
    [XmlElement("OBJECTS")]
    public SerializeObject[] Objects { get; set; }
}

public class SerializeObject
{
    [XmlAttribute("ITEM")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("TABLE_NAME")]
    public string Table_Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then you deserialize with:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableContainer));

using (var file = File.OpenText("sample.xml"))
{
    var data = (SerializableContainer)serializer.Deserialize(file);

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know where i made mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

leaving here a more complete example in case anyone needs: http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/serializedeserialize-objects-to-xml-with-c

Cheers!