# XML deserialize

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have some XML from survey system. Sample structure is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" standalone="yes" ?>
<document>
 <ID>100</ID>
 <DOCUMENT_DATA>
  <OWNER>SOME OWNER</OWNER>
  <CODING>WINDOWS-1250</CODING>
  <MAIN_DATA>
   <NAME>JOHN</NAME>
   <SURNAME>DOE</SURNAME>
   <SYSTEM_ID>000</SYSTEM_ID>
   <COUNTRY>GB</COUNTRY>
  </MAIN_DATA>
  <SUB_DATA>
   <STREET>SOME STREET</STREET>
   <BUILDING_NO>120</BUILDING_NO>
   <FLAT_NO>200</FLAT_NO>
   <CITY>LONDON</CITY>
  </SUB_DATA>
  <DESCRIPTION>
   <HAIR>BLACK</HAIR>
   <EYES>BROWN</EYES>
   <BODY>SLIM</BODY>
   <HEIGHT>176</HEIGHT>
   <STATUS>
    <STATUS_NAME>SINGLE</STATUS_NAME>
   </STATUS>
   <SEX>MALE</SEX>
   <TATOO>NO</TATOO>
   <PIERCING>NO</PIERCING>
  </DESCRIPTION>
  <INTEREST>
   <GENERAL>
    <SPORT>
     <MAIN>SURFING</MAIN>
     <TRAINING>EVERY DAY</TRAINING>
    </SPORT>
    <CARS>CLASSIC</CARS>
    <OTHER>MUSIC</OTHER>
   </GENERAL>
   <BOOKS>CRIMINALS</BOOKS>
   <MOVIES>THRILLER</MOVIES>
  </INTEREST>
 </DOCUMENT_DATA>
</document>
```

My task is to read XML file and deserialize it to objects in C#, using System.XML.Serialization reference and flags like [XmlAttribute], [XmlElement] and so on.
I'm not familiar with this technique, because I usually use standard and fast deserialization to DataSet type.
Can somebody help me with this task?

Comment: Did you try researching `"`C# XML serialization`"`? I'm sure there are millions of helpful examples that already exist?

Comment: Yes I've tried, I have seen some help threads even here, but I have a lot of work and this task is on me cause some collegue from my department is sick... As I said I'm not familiar with this tehnique.

Comment: SO doesn't do your work for you... you're going to have to put a little more effort into learning how to do this, and correctly, if you want it done.

Comment: Thank you for your help Tdorno. You are "extremely helpfull". I see you don't understand that sometimes somebody can be in very difficult situation. darth_phoenixx's answer helped me a lot so...

Comment: @szataniel did you get it done... ? That was a handy link of yours so was darth_phoenixx tip... Is there only ever the one '<document></document>' definition or are there many '<document></document>' then another '<document></document>' entries that need to be  Deserialized to a list<document>

Comment: @Monthy yes, task is done and structure generated by linked conevrter helped me to understand the whole thing about that. I don't know why "Paste Special" didn't worked, but darth_phoenixx answer was some clue for me.
Thank you for interesting.

Comment: @szataniel You're welcome bud... sometimes you need a little nudge before your realization permits itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix you can create a new class in Visual Studio, copy your XML to the clipboard and then choose "Edit", "Paste Special", "Paste XML as classes".

This will auto generate a class which you can then use for serialization/deserialization.

However, as @Tdorno suggests, there are plenty of helpful examples on the site, e.g.: [C# Deserialization xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135291/c-sharp-deserialization-xml-file)

Comment: "Paste Special" didn't worked for me, but I have found some other XML to C# converters on-line and used this link to convert my XML to classess structure: [link](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/). Thank You for help.

Comment: @MaciejS., that xml2cs converter saved me a bunch of times. The Visual Studio one (event the command-line one, that munches xsd) seem to have problems. The classes generated by the one you linked always work. It seems the company that developed it has folded a few years ago, so it would be cool to have an oensource version of it before the site dies too.

Answer (score 1):

LOL... I understand that sometimes somebody can be in very difficult situation szataniel…. So, don't know if this helps but using the Classes you created from your XML...

```
        // Deserialize single instance
        XmlSerializer serializerSingle = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document));//, new XmlRootAttribute("document"));
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"Path to your XML File"))
        {
            // 'ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document' is the 'Document' class in your XML Classes
            ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document dezerializedXMLSingle = (ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document)serializerSingle.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        }
```

that will Deserialize one instance of your 'document' in the XML...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

to  Deserialize a List I think your XML needs to have an outer root node like so (I stand to be corrected on that)....

```
<documents>
    <document>
    ...........
    </document>
    <document>
    ...........
    </document>
</documents>
```

then you can use the SAME classes as above...

```
        // Deserialize to List
        XmlSerializer serializerList = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document>), new XmlRootAttribute("documents"));
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"Path to your XML File"))
        {
            // 'ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document' is the 'Document' class in your XML Classes
            List<ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document> dezerializedXMLList = (List<ReadXML.Xml2CSharp.Document>)serializerList.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

I had to add a new root node (documents)and set XmlRootAttribute("documents") in order to use the same classes created from XML at Xml2CSharp.com

Comment: Yes, I got it in the same way just after using linked converter (please expand all comments to my description). Thank You for Your code - it ensures me, that my way of solving this task is right. :)